# Merge array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I merge two arrays in the way I explain below?

Using `print_r()`, this is the output of the two arrays;
The first one;

```
Array
(
    [created] => 1
    [approved] => 1
)
```

And the second array;

```
Array
(
    [created] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order created
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ROLE_USER
                )

            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [approve] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => approved
                        )

                )

        )

    [approved] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order approved
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ROLE_USER
                )

            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [order] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => ordered
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

How can I merge the arrays so that the `$value` (which will be either true or false) from the first array can be merged to the second one as a `[state]` as follows (There are comments at the lines `[state]`);

```
Array
(
    [created] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order created
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ROLE_USER
                )

            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [approve] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => approved
                        )

                )
            [state] => 1    // I want to add this line here from the other array
        )

    [approved] => Array
        (
            [label] => Order approved
            [roles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ROLE_USER
                )

            [next_states] => Array
                (
                    [order] => Array
                        (
                            [target] => ordered
                        )

                )
            [state] => 1    // I want to add this line here from the other array
        )
)
```

Note that the `$keys` from the first array and the second array are the same, but I want to add the `$values` to the arrays that serves as `$values` in the second array. What will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array1 as $a => $b)
    $array2[$a]['state'] = $b;
```

**edit:**

I've seen the comment. To set `state` to false when the right key doesn't exist in the first array, you can use the following code.

```
foreach($array2 as $a => &$b)
    $b['state'] = isset($array1[$a]) && $array1[$a];
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!

Comment: Quick question. How can I set `[state]` to 0 if something like [approve] is not (yet) in the first array? Because as of now it isn't added to the second array when it is not in the first array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge_recursive function. It used merge the array dynamically
[DEMO Please click here](https://eval.in/576283)

[Another example](https://eval.in/576290)

Comment: I see how it works, but it gives a `[0]` instead of `[state]`. And I also want to insert a default value for if it doesn't exist in the first array I want to add `[state] => 0`

Comment: you can't modify the first one into a array of an array. (i.e) created => array('state' => 0); Because if u have multiple array like 1st array it not good to name state dynamically